# Jackson Serialize: Include empty string if any

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to serialize a class into JSON string with jackson.

Class

```
public class Response {


  @JsonProperty("status")
  private Short status;

  @JsonProperty("data")
  @JsonRawValue
  private String data;

  @JsonProperty("message")
  @JsonRawValue
  private String message;
  
}
```

Using the following code to serialize

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
jsonFactory.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET,false);
ObjectMapper mapper;
mapper = new ObjectMapper(jsonFactory);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

Response responseInstance = new Response();
responseInstance.setStatus((short) 400);
responseInstance.setMessage("");
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(responseInstance));
```

I am getting the following value while serialization when value of message is "".

```
{
   "status": 400,
   "message":
}
```

Instead of

```
{
   "status": 400,
   "message":""
}
```

When the value is null, it is skipped from serialization which is expected. But when the value is "", i want that value be part of the serialization.
How do i inlcude "" in the value while serialization?

Comment: first one is not valid. Edit your question to add the code you use for the serialization

Comment: Jackson will most probably *not* generate the first shown JSON

Comment: @jhamon added more context

Comment: Yes, when message is null its  being skipped from serialization. which is ok for me. But when the value is "", i want that to be serialized

Comment: how are you checking that you are getting this {
   "status": 400,
   "message":
} ?

Comment: i am printing this in the log as string. also seeing this as part of REST response.

Comment: and when you print a non-empty string, do you see the quotation marks? as  { "status": 400, "message": "hello world"} ?

Comment: No, i am seeing without quotes. May be thats why i don't see quotes for empty value. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: How and where do you print? Please show an example that is fully reproducible

Comment: @knitti added reproducible code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@JsonRawValue`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.12.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html) is the "problem".

> Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field should be serialized by including literal String value of the property as is, **without quoting of characters**.
>
> […]
>
> Warning: the resulting JSON stream may be invalid depending on your input value.

In other words: everything works as expected. Your code tells the serializer to not add the quotes. And the serializer follows suit and doesn't add them.

If you need regular strings in JSON, then do not configure your serializer to remove them.

Comment: the problem is now that the message can be json string, Thats why i added @JsonRawValue.Otherwise it adds quotes to the string.

Comment: @vishnuk a JSON string is still a string. If you need to embed nested objects, then make your model reflect that fact.